# Export Image Google Cloud Engine (gce) to use the image local with VirtualBox

Tags: download, export, virtualbox, google-compute-engine, local

How can I export a gce Image to use it in a local Virtualbox?

I get the error:

```
error: No such device

gce-image-export.vmdk

gce-image-export.qcow2

gce-image-export.vdi
```

I use the command:

```
qemu-img convert -O vdi gce-image-export.qcow2 gce-image-export.vdi
```

I get by *.vmdk, *.qcow2, *.vdi all the the same error.

Did you have input for me?

Thanks

kivitendo

Answer (score 0):

You can export the image using the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#gcloud_1). You can see in the [following documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/export) all the use of the command and the flags.

```
gcloud compute images export \
--destination-uri <destination-uri> \
--image <image-name> \
--export-format  <format>
```

The `--export-format` flag exports the image to a format supported by QEMU using qemu-img. Valid formats include 'vmdk', 'vhdx', 'vpc', 'vdi', and 'qcow2'.

You can send it to a Bucket and later you can download it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i only can export from Google Cloud Platform (gce) to

- *.VMDK
- *.VHDX
- *.VPC
- *.qcow2

formats.

I must Virtualbox 6.1 change Virtualbox Machine to EFI Support.
If i use than rEFInd 0.12 as boothelper i can start my vce *.vmdk machine.

I get many errormessage and i don't can log in, in my vce *.vmdk machine. to repair the errormessage and install grub-efi to my vce *.vmdk machine.

My installed NextCloud server is starting.

How can i log in, to my machine?
root doesn't work.

I don't find any tutorial.

kivitendo

Comment: You could download the image as *.vdi too. Before export the image you need to change the local password. You can use the following [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#setting_up_a_local_password) to do it.